# VScode: device sync

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization

I'm starting with web dev and i work from PC and laptop. How can I sync both devices to have same settings and files synced?

Sometimes I just go forward on one device and then I have to pass the file to my other device, I want to know if there is any way to do it automatically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case for the new `edit sessions`, see [v1.69 release notes: edit sessions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_access-edit-sessions-across-vs-code-for-the-web-and-desktop).
`Edit Session(v1.69)/Cloud Changes(v1.74)`[v1.74](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74#_improvements-to-continue-working-on)

> This milestone we are announcing a preview of edit sessions in VS
> Code. Edit sessions enable you to bring your uncommitted changes along
> when you continue working on a repository wherever VS Code is
> available, whether that is VS Code for the Web, desktop VS Code, or
> across different machines.

Edit sessions are currently in preview behind the `workbench.experimental.editSessions.enabled` setting. In this initial release, you can use the following commands to store and resume your working changes:

Version - 1.69 
`Edit Sessions: Store Current Edit Session`
`Edit Sessions: Resume Latest Edit Session`

[Version - 1.74](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74#_improvements-to-continue-working-on) 
`Edit Sessions: Store Working Changes In Cloud`
`Edit Sessions: Resume Latest Changes From Cloud`

> To get started with edit sessions, use the `Edit Sessions: Store Current Edit Session` command and sign in with GitHub or Microsoft
> authentication when prompted. Then use the `Edit Sessions: Resume Latest Edit Session` command in a repository on another machine or VS
> Code instance to restore the working contents of all modified files to
> your workspace. You can sign out of edit sessions at any time using
> the `Edit Sessions: Sign Out` command.

In the release party video, she applies this to your use case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiRrggf1EF4&ab_channel=VisualStudioCode (about 5 minutes in).

Answer (score 0):

If the more limited [web based version](https://vscode.dev) works for you that might be the simplest solution. See more details at [Visual Studio Code for the Web](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web).

If you need the installed version

SYNCING VISUAL STUDIO CODE SETTINGS

[image]

On the bottom left corner of VS Code there is an icon that looks like a gear. If you click on that and then select `Turn on Settings Sync` then at the top of the screen you will be asked to 'Please sign in to synchronize your data across devices'.

[image]

You will then need to log into an MS or Github account and follow the directions from VS Code. Do this on each machine you want to sync settings with.

SYNCING FILES

You are probably best off using a version control tool such as GIT, which is built into VS Code and is explained in the VS Code [documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support).